# Existence of non-trivial affine functions on Hadamard spaces ?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

Let $X$ be a Hadamard space. Any two points $x$ and $y$ of $X$ have a unique midpoint $m = m(x,y)$.

Given $x$ and $y$ any two points of $X$, is it always possible to find an affine function $f : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x) \neq f(y)$ ? (where by "affine" I mean $\forall x',y' : f(m(x',y')) = \frac{f(x') + f(y')}{2})$ ?

Comment: Is this definition of affine equivalent to the standard one (that a function is affine if its restriction to every geodesic is affine)? If yes, then the answer is given by http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0511583
"Spaces with many affine functions" by Hitzelberger-Lytchak.

Comment: An example (the first example?) of a Hadamard space without this property is $\mathbb H^2$.

Comment: I'd say that the tripod is even an easier example. 

Comment: What's the tripod?

Comment: Tripod is the metric graph obtained by gluing three segments at a common vertex. 

Comment: Ah I see. I convinced myself that trees like that would be fine, which is of course ridiculous.

Comment: Yes, the "good" question was indeed "which Hadamard spaces have this property?". The comment of Igor Belegradek gives exactly what I was looking for. Thanks all.